# The one value of super square root function

Tags: functions, tetration

A function can not have more than one value.

i.e. we only take the positive value for $y$ where $y=\sqrt 4$

But what about the super square root?, if both value are positive real values like:

$$y=\sqrt {\left({\frac12}\right)^{\frac12}}_s$$

In this case we have two real values $y=\frac12$ , $y=\frac14$

**I wonder what value for $y$ should I accept in the following case:**

$$y=\sqrt{a}_s  (e^{-\frac1e}<a<1)$$

Comment: I assume you are asking the inverse of the tetration function for $f(x)=\exp_a^{\circ  x}$ for a in the range indicated?  Since the slope is negative at the real valued fixed point, the tetration function itself is does not have a well defined single accepted solution especially if one insists that f(-1)=0, f(0)=1, f(1)=a then oscillating towards the fixed point....  For example, I know of some complex valued solutions instead of real valued ones.  But a complete answer would be to just follow the Riemann surface in taking the inverse in the region of interest using the solution of interest.

Comment: @SheldonL Yes, my question was about the inverse function of $f(x)=x^x$ , I know this function can have many complex values, but in the relation I gave we get two real values and I am confused what value should be accepted sense the definition of function do not allow more than one value, consider the cubic root have three values one is real and the others are complex but the function accept the real one, note that, and I assume that you know it, that The square super root of $a$ is 2 real values when only $(e^{-\frac1e}<a<1)$.

Comment: $f(x)=exp_1^{\circ x}$ is not the same function as $f(x)=x^x$ and the 2nd one is a well defined real increasing real valued function for x>0 and has a straightforward inverse.  For x<0 just follow the Riemann surface for the region of interest.  Whereas the first one has multiple solutions that I know of which are complex instead of real valued; so the problem is mostly deciding which of several possible solutions (to the first one) the Op is interested in.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the function 
$$ \operatorname{ssqrt}(x) = \exp( W( \log( x  ))) $$
where $W$ is the Lambert-W (at its zero'th branch) and $x$ is in the range $ \exp(-\exp(-1))\approx 0.6922 \ldots 1$ as reference/as principal value.

This gives for $x= 1/2^{1/2}\approx 0.707 $
$$ \operatorname{ssqrt}(x) = 0.5 =1/2 $$
... for $x= 1/3^{1/3}\approx 0.693 $
$$ \operatorname{ssqrt}(x) \approx 0.403542672016 \approx 1/2.478 $$
... for $x= 1/4^{1/4}\approx 0.707 $
$$ \operatorname{ssqrt}(x) = 0.5 =1/2 $$
and so on

Comment: So for $x={1/4}^{1/4}$ we get $\operatorname{ssqrt}(x) = 0.5 =1/2$ but not $\operatorname{ssqrt}(x) = 0.25 =1/4$ according to the function $\operatorname{ssqrt}(x) = \exp( W( \log( x  )))$ ,because ${1/2}^{1/2}={1/4}^{1/4} \approx 0.707$, it is almost clear now.

Comment: @Pentapolis : yes; and there is -by my best knowledge- not yet a common convention for that norming for which you ask. So I wrote *"I would use...as the reference"*